# I'm getting unusual behavior with angular-strap typeahead on PhoneGap with Samsung softkeyboards

Tags: cordova, typeahead, angular-strap, soft-keyboard

The predictive text feature on the Samsung soft keyboard is causing an odd issue with Typeahead fields.

I'm building an angular app, and using angular-strap for typeahead fields. I then use PhoneGap to convert it into iOS and Android apps.

The problem only happens when predictive text is turned on, it somehow interacts with the typeahead field causing characters to repeated, so if I type "adv" when I type the "v"  the input changes from "ad" to "adadv". It also creates an odd behavior when deleting, it moves the cursor to the end of the word after each delete. So to delete the first ad in the example I would have to set the cursor after the d, delete, then set the cursor to after the a.

I only get this issue when I use the app, if I open the angular app in a browser on my phone the typeahead fields work fine.

I'm also only seeing this on a Galaxy S6 Edge+ with the Samsung keyboard. On a Galaxy Note 2, with the Samsung Keyboard and Predictive text, it works. On a Moto E Google Keyboard, it works.

I've tried to add the attribute autocomplete="off" to the typeahead input, but I'm pretty sure that attribute is only used by browsers. It didn't fix the problem for me anyway.

Is there any way to prevent the predictive text from interacting with the field?

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Any luck?

Comment: It affected too few devices to warrant us spending more time on for the moment, so we just told users that they need to disable their device predictive text if it conflicts with our type ahead fields.

Comment: I was having this issue mainly on numeric fields.  I read somewhere there was a workaround on numeric fields to set them as type="tel" and predictive text apparently shuts off in that case.  That helped me but won't help you unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that adding a setTimeout to typeahead's _onInput method fixes this.

In typeahead.jquery.js, I replaced:

`_onInput: function onInput() {
    this._setQuery(this.getInputValue());
    this.clearHintIfInvalid();
    this._checkLanguageDirection();
}`

with:

`_onInput: function onInput() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () { 
        self._setQuery(self.getInputValue());
        self.clearHintIfInvalid();
        self._checkLanguageDirection();
    }, 0);
}`

This allows the keyboard/browser to do its thing before the typeahead code kicks in (if you run this in a debugger you can see the text changing during this time).

This isn't a very good solution because you'll have to do it again if you ever get a new version of typeahead. I do the replacement as part of my build process, which helps a little, but a better solution would be to submit a pull request. I don't know the project that well though, so not sure if the authors would want to make such a change.